# Let $X$ and $Y$ be no empty sets, then $|X|\le |Y|$ if and only if there exists $f\colon Y\to X$ onto

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation

> **Theorem.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be no empty sets. Then 
>   $$\big(|X|\le |Y|\big)\quad\text{if and only if}\quad\big(\exists\;f\colon Y\to X\;\text{onto}\big).$$

**Proof.**$(\Rightarrow)$ Let $|X|\le|Y|$, then by definition exists $g\colon X\to Y$ injective, if $g$ is onto we finished. If $g$ is not onto, we consider $g\colon X\to g(X)\subset Y$ which is invertible, therefore we can consider $g^{-1}\colon g(X)\to X$. We can extend $g^{-1}$ to an onto function $f$ on all Y in a following way: let $x_0\in X$, 
$$
f(y):=
\begin{cases}
g^{-1}(y)
& \text{if $y\in g(X)$} \\
x_0 & \text{if $y\in Y\setminus g(X)$}.
\end{cases}
$$
The application $f\colon Y\to X$ is onto.

> **Question 1.** Is it correct?

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $f\colon Y\to X$ onto and we define $g\colon X\to Y$ in the follow way: for all $x\in X$, $g(x)=y$, where $y\in Y$ is such that $x=f(y)$ (we remember that $f$ is onto). We observe that for all $x\in X$ we have 
$$f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))=f(y)=x.$$
Therefore, $f\circ g=\text{id}_X$.

> **Question 2.** If $f$ is onto and $f\circ g$ invertible, can we conclude that $g$ is injective? If the answer is yes, How can I show it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to slow down on the symbols in titles, in the present case these were really unneeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1** is correct, though you don't need to separately handle the case when $g$ is onto.

**Q2** Yes, moreover if $f\circ g$ is injective with arbitrary $f$, it follows that $g$ must be injective. 
Note that the axiom of choice is used in order to simultaneously pick a preimage $y$ for all elements $x$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, since $f\colon Y\to X$ is onto, then for all $x\in X$, exists $y\in Y$ such that $x=f(y)$. We define $g\colon X\to Y$, in the follow way: for all $x\in X$ we choose one $y\in Y$ such that $x=f(y)$. Here we use the axiom of the choice so that $g$ is well defined, because there could be more than one $y$ such that $x=f(y)$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. Note also that the axiom of choice can actually be rephrased as 'every onto function has a right inverse': if a family $(X_i)_I$ of nonempty sets is given, we can form their disjoint union as $X:=\{(i,x) : i\in I,\, x\in X_i\}$ and define an onto map $X\to I$ by $(i,x)\mapsto i$. Its sections (i.e., right inverses) are basically the *choice functions* $I\to X$